# Mod_pagespeed delete cache?

Tags: wordpress, apache, caching, pagespeed

We have a server (OVH - France), with Apache and [mod_pagespeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/mod). On this server, I have an installation of WordPress.

I made a change in a Javascript file in my theme, but pagespeed don't understand there is a new file, and keeps loading the original javascript file. `js/ui.js.pagespeed********`

I made the change two weeks ago, rebooted the server this morning, and it is still loading the original Javascript file.

How can I delete the pagespeed cache?

On my server, in `/var/mod_pagespeedcache/http,3A/,2Fwww.myURL.fr/wp-content/themes/mytheme/js`, I see the `ui.js.pagespeed.jm.************.js`.

Could I just delete this file?

Comment: For future questions, I'd suggest you contact us directly at https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/mod-pagespeed-discuss where you are more likely to get a quick response.

Comment: Duplicate of serverfault question : http://serverfault.com/questions/435412/flush-mod-pagespeed-cache-in-debian

Answer (score 16):

Google's PageSpeed docs on [Legacy Flushing Of Entire Cache](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/system#flush_cache_legacy) suggests this:

```bash
sudo touch /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush
```

Comment: Just a heads up - I have tried this multiple times to no avail. I have also seen other responses saying that it didn't work.

Comment: works for me.  maybe due to which OS and pagespeed version.  mine is Debian 7.10 with X-Mod-Pagespeed "1.9.32.14-0"

Comment: If doesn't work, try ctrl+f5 in browser to reload page with cache clear.

Comment: This worked for me on Debian 10, Apache/2.4.38, mod-pagespeed-stable 1.13.35.2-r0

Answer (score 7):

From: https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/faq#ignores-changes

> There are two distinct cache-times at play when you use mod_pagespeed:
>
> The origin TTL which mod_pagespeed uses to refresh its internal
>   server-side cache.
>
> The TTL with which mod_pagespeed serves rewritten resources to
>   browsers. When mod_pagespeed first reads your reousrce file, it uses
>   the origin TTL to figure out how often to re-examine the origin CSS
>   file. Assume your origin TTL is 1 day. Once mod_pagespeed has that
>   file in cache, it will not go back & re-check that file for a day.
>   Changing the TTL after mod_pagespeed has put the resource in its cache
>   will not help because mod_pagespeed is not going to reload the
>   resource until the one in its cache expires, or you [clear its
>   cache](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/system#flush_cache).
>
> We recommend an origin TTL of 10 minutes, which provides reasonable
>   responsiveness when you update a file. If you try to make it much
>   smaller, then your server will need to refresh it more frequently.
>   This adds server load and reduces optimization.
>
> To see changes to your files more quickly while developing, [flush the
>   cache](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/system#flush_cache)
>   on your server(s).
>
> If your environment allows you to enable
>   [ModPagespeedLoadFromFile](https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/mod_pagespeed/domains#ModPagespeedLoadFromFile),
>   you can get the best of both worlds because mod_pagespeed can
>   eliminate its internal server-side cache.

Answer (score 4):

Flushing the cache of a specific page in Pagespeed requires that the server support cache purging. In Apache, this means `ModPagespeedEnableCachePurge on` in the site's configuration. In Nginx, you'll need `pagespeed EnableCachePurge on;` instead. This setting allows you to send a specially-crafted HTTP request to force-purge a specific page in Pagespeed. For example with cURL:

`curl 'http://example.com/pagespeed_admin/cache?purge=path/file.ext'`

There is also another method for purging single pages in the cache (`curl --request PURGE 'http://www.example.com/path/file.ext'`), however this requires an extra, optional config option in your site's config file (`ModPagespeedPurgeMethod PURGE` for Apache and `pagespeed PurgeMethod PURGE;` for Nginx).

For more information, please refer to the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/system#flush_cache) describing this process for more detail.

Answer (score 3):

```
sudo touch /var/cache/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush
```

Load the page again. You should see the changes

Answer (score 3):

On bitnami AWS server (lightsail) use this commands:

```
sudo touch /opt/bitnami/apache2/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush
```

Restart Apache:

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Here is the [help page](https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/components/pagespeed/).

Answer (score 0):

Flush cache nginx pagespeed

```
sudo touch /var/cache/ngx_pagespeed/cache.flush
```